# Isolating techniques for single power supply

Tags: power-supply, adc, power-electronics, ground, isolation

[image: Power Supply Configuration]

Hello. I am working on a product which is used for measuring current from multiple channels(16 nos per device) using an onboard ADC. The device is powered by a 24VDC supply. Now even though the devices will not be connected together at the consumer end, at my testing and calibration station it will be great if I could power multiple devices(say 10 nos) using a single supply as my operating current isn't too high. As shown in the figure, I would want to use the lower configuration which has only one supply. The problem I'm facing is that because of the common supply(and specifically because of the common Ground terminal from what I can understand), the readings of my ADC are unstable and shifted. One solution I found was to use an isolated power supply. But I wanted to know if there is some other way to isolate without changing my present power supply. What I can do easily is make a small power distribution/isolation board if I can find some cheap solution to the problem. If I am wrong about the problem being isolation please help as well. Thank you.

Comment: Just use a DC-DC convertor and build your analog front end isolated from your back end.

Comment: You could go with something like https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/cui-inc/PDS1-S24-S24-M-TR/102-2684-2-ND/4009609 per current meter, but I'm not sure if that solution will be cheaper than an isolated power supply.

Comment: So you want to say that the set-up of first picture is working, but the second not, don't you? I don't think that's the reason for having unstable and shifted ADC data. I see the two pictures as electrically identical. I would try to measure the power supply quality, and the I-V converters outputs with an osciloscope and figure out what is the source of the instability. It's important to show us where the ADC is in the two pictures and how it's connected to the I-V converters

Comment: I am using a Shunt resistance which causes a voltage drop when current is flown, which is then sent parallelly to my ADC channels. Yes @judoka_acl the upper one is working and just by changing the configuration to the bottom one, I am observing a shifted reading. I tried multiple combinations of my setup but I still feel it is something to do with isolated ground reference.

Comment: "I am using a Shunt resistance which causes a voltage drop when current is flown, which is then sent parallelly to my ADC channels." - Please provide a detailed schematic of the shunt and interface between it and your ADC, including connections to the 24V supply and test current supply.